# How to get last item by date (but without grouping)

Tags: mysql

I dont get how to get item name in my database by last date.

I have in DB:

```
id  | code | date_field | name  |  sales |
----+------+------------+-------+--------+
1   |  AA1 | 20-10-2012 | asd   |    4
2   |  AA1 | 20-13-2012 | asd   |    10
3   |  AA1 | 20-17-2012 | asd   |    20
4   |  AA2 | 20-20-2012 | zad   |    13
5   |  AA3 | 20-10-2012 | 3ad   |    4 
6   |  AA4 | 20-15-2012 | bez   |    0
7   |  AA4 | 20-17-2012 | bez   |    1
8   |  AA4 | 20-22-2012 | bez   |    0
9   |  AA5 | 20-21-2012 | sda2  |    3
10  |  AA6 | 20-21-2012 | goo   |    5
```

i need to get:

```
id  | code | date_field | name  | sales |
----+------+------------+-------+-------+
3   |  AA1 | 20-17-2012 | asd   |   20
4   |  AA2 | 20-20-2012 | zad   |   13
5   |  AA3 | 20-10-2012 | 3ad   |   4
8   |  AA4 | 20-22-2012 | bez   |   1
9   |  AA5 | 20-21-2012 | sda2  |   3
10  |  AA6 | 20-21-2012 | goo   |   5
```

i think i should use something like:

```
SELECT MAX(date) as date_field, code, name from table
group by date_field
```

.. 
I'm a right?

P.S - look that 'sales' field is not grouping!

Comment: What kind of dates are that? Does seems to be wrong.

Comment: whatever this dates are, i just for example write it down.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT date_field as `date`, code, name, sales
from my_table
group by date_field
order by sales desc
```

Comment: thats way field sales grouping too, ?

Comment: @remizpez: No, you just group by date_field. I tried it. it works. Can you confirm?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:-

```
SELECT a.date as date_field, a.code, a.name from table a
where a.id = (select max(b.id) from table b where b.name = a.name)
and a.date = (select max(c.date) from table c where c.name = a.name)
order by sales desc
```

Answer (score 0):

correlated sub-queries are always time performance hits.. even if this is a small set, who knows how large the basis may become.  I would suggest an inner pre-query to just get the max date per code, then re-join to get that record.  Ensure an index on (code, date_field)

```
select
      yt2.*
   from
      ( select yt.code,
               max( yt.date_field ) maxbyDate
           from
              YourTable yt
           group by
              yt.code ) PreQuery
      JOIN YourTable yt2
         on PreQuery.Code = yt2.code
        AND PreQuery.maxByDate = yt2.date_field
```